# Internal error code, kksgaItLvl_Setup

Tags: oracle, index, partitioning, oracle-12c

A simple query fails with the error. Has anyone faced this issue or has any solutions?

```
   SELECT MAX(some_value)
      FROM some_table
    WHERE some_id = 62328188199
       AND some_name = 'someParameter'
       AND someother_name = 'name';
```

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kksgaItLvl_Setup: desc],
>   [3], [3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Comment: `ORA-00600` means "Fill out an SR with Oracle Support".  These are internal bugs.  Only Oracle can truly solve them.  In most cases, the solution is "upgrade your database".  In other cases, you'll need to rewrite the query.  Someone might know the workaround.  But, access to the official document requires a Support contract.

Answer (score 1):

(Link accessible only by registration to Oracle Support):

[Bug 21266085 - ORA-600 [kksgaItLvl_Setup: asc] from a query against an interval partitioned table (Doc ID 21266085.8)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=21266085.8)

> ```
> The fix for 21266085 is first included in
>
> 12.2.0.1 (Base Release)
> 12.1.0.2.161018 (Oct 2016) Database Patch Set Update (DB PSU)
> 12.1.0.2.160719 (Jul 2016) Database Proactive Bundle Patch
> 11.2.0.4.160719 Exadata Database Bundle Patch (Jul 2016)
> 12.1.0.2.160419 (Apr 2016) Bundle Patch for Windows Platforms
> ```